# Как поместить имена или индексы pictureBoxов после определенной проверки, в новый список или массив, для дальнейшей работы с ними?

Tags: c#

Почему при вызове `ToString` на списке (для проверки) не выводятся добавленные в него названия pictureBoxов?

```
public List<PictureBox> ArrayImg = new List<PictureBox>();
public Form3GameAI()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ArrayImg.Add(pictureBox1);
    ArrayImg.Add(pictureBox2);
    ArrayImg.Add(pictureBox3);
    ArrayImg.Add(pictureBox4);
    ArrayImg.Add(pictureBox5);
    ArrayImg.Add(pictureBox6);
    ArrayImg.Add(pictureBox7);
    ArrayImg.Add(pictureBox8);
    ArrayImg.Add(pictureBox9);
}
public void AnalisysEmptyNoobSaiBot()
{
    List<string> ArrayIndexPictureBox = new List<string>(); 
    //Если ячейка включена добавляем ее имя в список
    if (lblPlayerRun1.Visible)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayImg.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ArrayImg[i].Enabled)
            {
                string indexer = ArrayImg[i].Name; 
                ArrayIndexPictureBox.Add(indexer);
                MessageBox.Show(indexer.ToString()); //Так имена выводит, просто для проверки
                MessageBox.Show(ArrayIndexPictureBox.ToString()); //А так нет
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помещать `pictureBox`-ы в список Вы уже умеете. После этого работать нужно с элементами списка, а не с самим списком:

```
//показываем первый элемент нового списка
MessageBox.Show(ArrayIndexPictureBox[0]); 
//или последний
MessageBox.Show(ArrayIndexPictureBox[ArrayIndexPictureBox.Count - 1]);
```

Либо вывести весь список в строку через `String.Join`:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Join(",", ArrayIndexPictureBox));
```

P.S. Называйте локальные переменные со строчной буквы и используйте Linq:

```
if (lblPlayerRun1.Visible)
{
    var enabledImagesNames = ArrayImg.Where(i => i.Enabled)
                                    .Select(i => i.Name)
                                    .ToList();
    ...
}
```